# Socket IO Swift Client Emit Message with ACK

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, express, socket.io

According to the docs for the [socket.io swift client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) in order to emit a message with an acknowledgement, we do:

```
socket.emitWithAck(MESSAGE, data).timingOut(after: 2) {data in
   print("Callback called")
}
```

On the server side I can do:

```
socket.on(MESSAGE, data =>

);
```

but how do I acknowledge this message from the server so that the callback gets called in my iOS app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this we pass a callback in as follows:

```
socket.on(MESSAGE, (params, callback) =>
  myHandlerFunc(socket, params, callback)
);
```

where `myHandlerFunc` has the following signature:

```
const myHandlerFunc = (socket, params, callback) => {

...

}
```

and then inside `myHandlerFunc` we use it as follows:

```
return callback(JSON.stringify(result));
```

or

```
return callback(error);
```